# Error: Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value, Scenario explained in description

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I have 2 dropdowns, if I selected 1st one, based on that I am populating second dropdown list, same as states in country. for example when I select 1st dropdown, value is India, in second dropdown india's states are populating, but when I am selecting 2nd time, value is America, then I am getting below error;
Error: Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

How to fix this,

```
  AppDropdown(
    hint: Text('Select country'),
    onChanged: (value) {
      _getAllStates(value);
      setState(() {
        _countryDetails.country = value.toString();
        countryID = value;
      });
    },
    validator: (val) => (val == null ? 'Required' : null),
    items: _countryList
        .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(e.country.toString().toUpperCase()),
            value: e.id))
        .toList(),
  ),
 
  AppDropdown(
    hint: Text('Select state'),
    items: _stateList
        .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(e.state.toString().toUpperCase()),
            value: e.id))
        .toList(),
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        _stateDetails.state = value.toString();
        stateID = value;
      });
    },
    validator: (val) => (val == null ? 'Required' : null),
  ),
```

Comment: Please share the code inside your _getAllStates()

Comment: The error code is saying exactly what's wrong. Two or more of your `DropDownMenuItem`s have the same thing in their `value`. Make it so that doesn't happen and the error will go away.

Comment: @AnkitKumarMaurya

`_getAllStates(int countryID) {
    List<StateDetails> stateDetails =
        _helper!.getAllStatesByCountry(countryID);
    setState(() {
      _stateList = stateDetails;
    });
  }`
that method will give stateList based on countryId